# Invalid JSON from google ml engine

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I have deployed a TensorFlow object detection model on AI Platform. The model configuration is below:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['image_bytes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: encoded_image_string_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 4)
        name: detection_boxes:0
    outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300)
        name: detection_classes:0
    outputs['detection_features'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
        name: detection_features:0
    outputs['detection_multiclass_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 2)
        name: detection_multiclass_scores:0
    outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300)
        name: detection_scores:0
    outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: num_detections:0
    outputs['raw_detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 4)
        name: raw_detection_boxes:0
    outputs['raw_detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 2)
        name: raw_detection_scores:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I am using the following code for generating predictions

```
    def predict_json(project, model, request, version=None):
        """Send json data to a deployed model for prediction.

        Args:
            project (str): project where the Cloud ML Engine Model is deployed.
            model (str): model name.
            instances ([Mapping[str: Any]]): Keys should be the names of Tensors
                your deployed model expects as inputs. Values should be datatypes
                convertible to Tensors, or (potentially nested) lists of datatypes
                convertible to tensors.
            version: str, version of the model to target.
        Returns:
            Mapping[str: any]: dictionary of prediction results defined by the
                model.
        """
        # Create the ML Engine service object.
        # To authenticate set the environment variable
        # GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = <service-account-file>
        service = build('ml', 'v1')
        name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)
        if version is not None:
            name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)
        response = service.projects().predict(
            name=name,
            body=request
        )
        response.execute()
        if 'error' in response:
            raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

        return response['predictions']

img = Image.open(image)
output_str = io.BytesIO()
img.save(output_str, "JPEG")
image_byte_array = output_str.getvalue()
image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_byte_array).decode()
request = {"instances": [{"image_bytes": {"b64": image_base64}}]}

prediction = predict_json('handdetector', 'fastercnn', request)
```

The predictions returns but one tag is missing which is 'detection_scores'. Moreover the response is not proper JSON which results in the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/PycharmProjects/sign-language/Sign-Language-Translation/detection/predict.py", line 60, in <module>
    prediction = predict_json('handdetector', 'fastercnn', request)
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/PycharmProjects/sign-language/Sign-Language-Translation/detection/predict.py", line 36, in predict_json
    response.execute()
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/sign-language/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/sign-language/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 857, in execute
    return self.postproc(resp, content)
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/sign-language/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/model.py", line 216, in response
    return self.deserialize(content)
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/sign-language/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/model.py", line 274, in deserialize
    body = json.loads(content)
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/syedmustufainabbasrizvi/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 9 column 1976399 (char 1999826)
```

I manually inspected the body of the response and found that it doesnot return valid json as some of the brackets are also missing which then results in json error when it tries to load back to json internally. Does any one encounter similar experience with it.

Comment: If you test the same model with TF serving do you get a valid response? What about `gcloud predict local` command? Can you post the response ?

Comment: This seems to be related to the other thread we have. You can only pass 100 online requests.

Answer (score 0):

Has there been any resolution for this? @gogasca I am having the same issue.

Best I can guess is there is a size threshold on AI Platform. I have a object detection model that is set up to predict 100 classes and its saved_model.pb is ~55MB and it works great... I have a second model that predicts almost 1000 classes and its saved_model.pb is ~160MB and that model chokes the error above.

Maybe find a way to use tf serving instead of AI Platform, or make a smaller model. But that's just a guess, as AI Platform has minimal documentation on this problem.

In my case **a smaller model** was the answer -> which is unfortunate, because the 1000 classes is more appropriate for my particular use case. But nonetheless, a resolution to the problem you posted.